# React Table not updating when array change in useState

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
const Registration = props => {

  const [data, setData] = useState(props.mainData)
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc")

  const SortHeader = (header) => {
    if (order === "asc") {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[header].toLowerCase() > b[header].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setData(sorted)
      setOrder("dsc")
    }
    if (order === "dsc") {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[header].toLowerCase() < b[header].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setData(sorted)
      setOrder("asc")
    }
  }
...
<tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th onClick={() => SortHeader('a')}
                      data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                      data-tooltip-content={`${data.length} records, Click to sort`}>A</th>
                  <th onClick={() => SortHeader('b')}
                      data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                      data-tooltip-content={`${data.length} records, Click to sort`}>B</th>
                  <th onClick={() => SortHeader('c')}
                      data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                      data-tooltip-content={`${data.length} records, Click to sort`}>C</th>
                  <th onClick={() => SortHeader('d')}
                      data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                      data-tooltip-content={`${data.length} records, Click to sort`}>D</th>
                  <th onClick={() => SortHeader('e')}
                      data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                      data-tooltip-content={`${data.length} records, Click to sort`}>E</th>
                  <th onClick={() => SortHeader('f')}
                      data-tooltip-id="my-tooltip"
                      data-tooltip-content={`${data.length} records, Click to sort`}>F</th>
                </tr>
                {data.map((val, key) => {
                  if (val.a.substring(0, 4) !== "YYYY") {
                    return (
                      <tr key={key} data-item={val}>
                        <td data-item="a">{a}</td>
                        <td>{val.b}</td>
                        <td>{val.c}</td>
                        <td>{val.d}</td>
                        <td>{val.e}</td>
                        <td>{GetCleanDate(val.f)}</td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                  } else {
                    return null
                  }
                })}
                </tbody>
```

the Sorting is working fine, but when I add or remove a new record to props.mainData the table doesn't refresh automatically, so I have to reload the page.
I made some research and people suggest to use "useEffect()" but honestly I don't how to implement it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add `useEffect` like following.

```
const Registration = ({ mainData }) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState(mainData)
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc")

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(mainData)
  }, [mainData])

  const SortHeader = (header) => {
    if (order === "asc") {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[header].toLowerCase() > b[header].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setData(sorted)
      setOrder("dsc")
    }
    if (order === "dsc") {
      const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) =>
        a[header].toLowerCase() < b[header].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setData(sorted)
      setOrder("asc")
    }
  }
  ...
```